# Highlight reduction in images

Tags: image-processing, highlight, image-enhancement

I am trying to reduce the highlights in an image caused by a high intensity light source.
I tried various softwares and I found that "**Highlight Reduction**" works for me.
But I am not able to understand the actual **processing behind a Highlight Reduction**.
Can anybody please help me regarding that ?

Comment: You're going to have to give us more information. Is "Highlight Reduction" a program? (if so, add at least a link) Or is it an option in a program? (if so, which program?)

Comment: I have tried this in almost all major Image edition softwares. Naming a few would be Adobe Lightroom, Snapseed for Android.

Comment: So you're assuming they all do the same thing?

Comment: They all have a highlight adjustment option. And I want to know what exactly is happening in that highlight adjustment option.

Comment: What I'm saying is that it's unlikely that any of these programs implement the same thing for highlight reduction. The name of the option might match, but it's not a standardized algorithm, and so what actually happens to the image will be different for different programs.

Comment: But they may follow certain basic algorithm right. I want to know what is that algorithm ?

Comment: Your question is far too vague and broad for Stack Overflow. You also don't even show any sample images nor are you specific about what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps http://answers.opencv.org/question/92887/specular-highlights-detection/ may give some hints. At least 3 papers are cited there:

> Searching around the literature I found the following 3 interesting papers: Real-time
>   highlight removal using intensity ratio, Efficient and Robust Specular Highlight Removal
>   and Fast and High Quality Highlight Removal from A Single Image. The first two that 
>   they provide the code as well gave not that good results.